# Adding increasing key to Hash

Tags: ruby

PHP allows to add values to array like this:

```
array[]='a' # result: arr[0]='a'
array[]='a' # result: arr[1]='a'
...
```

How to achieve similar result with Ruby?

UPDATED:
forgot to say, that I need to make some extra hashes inside, like

```
'a'=>{1=>1}...
```

UPDATE 2:
First update can be a little bit confusing, so there is my full source, which doesn't work. It has to make multiple records of `@value` hash in session[:items][0], session[:items][1]...

```
@value = {'id'=>id, 'quantity'=>1, "property_categories"=>params[:property_categories]}

if !session[:items].present?
  session[:items] = @value
else 
  session[:items].push(@value)
end
```

UPDATE 3:
data should look like:

```
[0=>{'id'=>id, 'quantity'=>1, "property_categories"=>{1=>1}},
1=>{'id'=>id, 'quantity'=>1, "property_categories"=>{1=>1}}]...
```

Comment: show a demo..how you would do it in PHP(updated part).. Then we will think in Ruby,,

Comment: Good.. What should your final dat look like ? It would help to answer fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, if `session[:items]` is not present, you are assigning `@value`(which is a `Hash`) to it. So next time it will try to push items to Hash.

If you need an `Array` for `session[:items]`, this should work

```
if !session[:items].present?
  session[:items] = [@value] # Here create an array with @value in it
else 
  session[:items].push(@value)
end
```

**EDIT**
   I see you have updated your question. So here is my  updated answer

```
if !session[:items].present?
  session[:items] = { 0 => @value }
else
  session[:items][ session[:items].keys.max + 1 ] = @value
end
```

Comment: Previous version was better in my case. I didin't knew that Ruby don't need numbers to put hashes inside as PHP does

Comment: Added my prev version back :)

Answer (score 3):

this should work:

```
arr << 'a'
```

or this:

```
arr.push('a')
```

source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html

Answer (score 2):

Simply push to the array using `<<`

```
array = []
array << 'a' # array == ["a"]
array << 'a' # array == ["a", "a"]
```